# RabbitMQ Rest API Create Exchange Failed

Tags: rabbitmq

I am creating a Spring Boot application and I want to create an exchange via rest api:

```
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    String auth = "guest:guest";
    byte[] encodedAuth = Base64.encodeBase64(auth.getBytes(Charset.forName("US-ASCII")) );
    String authHeader = "Basic " + new String( encodedAuth );
    headers.set( "Authorization", authHeader );

    String uri = "http://localhost:15672/api/exchanges/%2f/my-new-exchange-new";

    String input = "{\"type\":\"direct\",\"durable\":\"true\"}";

    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(input,headers);

    ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.PUT, entity, String.class);

    System.out.println(response);
```

However I always get the error:

```
PUT request for "http://localhost:15672/api/exchanges/%252f/my-new-exchange-new" resulted in 404 (Not Found); invoking error handler
```

Could you please help me with a hint? Thank you!

You can try it out if you want here: https://github.com/pkid/rabbittest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is most likely the URL encoding applied to your `uri` variable by the `RestTemplate` given the `%252f` returned in the error. To avoid that, you need to use `RestTemplate` methods that work with `URI` and tell it to assume the URL is already encoded:

```
String uri = "http://localhost:15672/api/exchanges/%2F/my-new-exchange-new";
restTemplate.exchange(UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(uri)
                                          .build(true)
                                          .toUri(), HttpMethod.PUT, entity, String.class);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is it! Owesome!